# How to survive a 24 hours of heavy lava rain?

Tags: survival, natural-disasters

It happened all of a sudden, one day it started raining heavily, not ordinary rain but hot lava rain, those who were in their houses rushed to their well equipped basements waiting for it to stop, however those who were outside : working, studying, shopping, walking or driving, how will they survive the first hours of such unexpected event knowing that it rained like that all over the world ?

Comment: Does this "rain" actually reach the ground as molten lava? I could imagine the outer shell of each drop cooling enough on the way down to solidify, meaning that the "rain" is now a barrage of lava-filled rocks. Ouch.

Comment: Yes it does, in my imaginary world :)

Comment: How big are these droplets? It sounds like everyone is going to drown in lava if they're too big.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon They are like normal raindrops in size.

Comment: @Javert Welcome to the site! You question as it stands is very open-ended. There are several unclear elements as well, you say people in their houses are fine, but would the houses not be burning to the ground and/or collapsing under the added weight of liquid stone on the roof? Please provide additional details.

Comment: @Samuel Thanks for the warm welcome, i am new to the site but i will try my best to develop my ideas furthermore in the future, any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it would depend on the size and composition of the lava. Boulder-sized blobs containing volcanic gases would make it hard to survive unless you entered the sewer system or happened to stumble upon a waterfall cave (not too likely), although any regular cave would significantly increase your odds of survival. Even when being submerged in the ocean you would not survive the impact of a 'droplet', and the gases released would make surfacing to breathe a tad risky too.

If the size of the lava were comparable to actual raindrops and gases were not to be considered, people could likely survive by using inflammable objects to shield from the rain, since this form of lava would cool down rapidly and would actually start working as a shield for any new raindrops.

Still, the sewer system would seem like the most widespread and safe hiding place.

Comment: Hiding in the sewer system is really an excellent idea for people outside !!! I used the word **heavy** to indicate the persistence not the size of the drops.

Comment: I do understand the definition of heavy rain! It just isn't clear to me what size the 'droplets' would be. Hiding under a car or even in the basement when a huge, molten boulder rains on your roof will still result in you having a baaaad time! Lava is obviously quite heavy.

Comment: It's like actual raindrops in size, but it's rapid and persistent.

Comment: But won't the lava follow gravity and leak into the sewers?

Comment: This is small drops of lava raining down. Most likely it will not be fluid the moment it touches down, or it will be very very slow-moving.

Answer (score 2):

If this is nothing that happens on a regular basis people won't be ready for it. Get under some kind of roof, chance is good even a little shack will protect you enough since your lava drops won't hold much Thermal energy.(I would love to do some calculation here but I am just not capable of it. Maybe someone else will)

Also a body of water like in @Carlos answer will do fine as well, best would be inside a body of water with a roof on top so you don't get burned while breathing and still have some failsafe in case the roof **does** get destroyed because of prolonged rain.

Answer (score 1):

Get into a body of water and hope it doesn't last too long. If it's not too much lava the water will keep you cool, and you can still stick your head up for air.

Comment: That's possible if you live near the sea, but if you live far away from sea you will eventually burn trying to reach it.

Comment: Swimming pools?

Comment: That could work but sticking your head up for air is very risky, you could get burnt.